# bandwidth larger than tc htb ceil in 10-Gigabit network

Tags: linux, tc, htb

In classid 88:201, I set `ceil 200mibps`, but in fact data can be send at 218 Mibps.

Any one have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers!

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 88: htb default 202
tc class add dev eth0 parent 88: classid 88:89 htb rate 1250mibps ceil 1250mibps
tc class add dev eth0 parent 88:89 classid 88:200 htb rate 1130mibps ceil 1250mibps  
tc class add dev eth0 parent 88:89 classid 88:201 htb rate 100mibps ceil 200mibps
tc class add dev eth0 parent 88:89 classid 88:202 htb rate 20mibps ceil 100mibps
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not a certain answer, but here are some ideas.

Are you sure your 218Mib does not include upload **and** download ?

What is the burst value for 88:201 ? For how long can 88:201 send 218Mibps ?

If you change the ceil, is still the class able to send too much data ? The same percentage ? The same amount of Mibps ? Same questions if you look at 88:202.

Comment: First, thanks for your ideas.  burst value set 2000k, use default burst value has the same result.   when ceil set less than 160Mibps, the class is not able to send too much data.

Comment: Once again I'm in troubleshooting mode, with no certitude : it looks like an issue with how tc-htb count the bandwidth. I have read that htb is not good at limiting traffic at very high bandwidth (500Mbps), I don't know if it is still true. You could try with tc-hfsc to confirm htb is the cause, hfsc is supposed to be **really** better at high bandwidth. Just to make it sure, do you already know in tc, "mbps" is MegaBytes per second, and you have to use "mbit" to specify MegaBits per second ?

Comment: the define in tc code{
 { "bit", 1. },
 { "Kibit", 1024. },
 { "kbit", 1000. },
 { "mibit", 1024.*1024. },
 { "mbit", 1000000. },
 { "gibit", 1024.*1024.*1024. },
 { "gbit", 1000000000. },
 { "tibit", 1024.*1024.*1024.*1024. },
 { "tbit", 1000000000000. },
 { "Bps", 8. },
 { "KiBps", 8.*1024. },
 { "KBps", 8000. },
 { "MiBps", 8.*1024*1024. },
 { "MBps", 8000000. },
 { "GiBps", 8.*1024.*1024.*1024. },
 { "GBps", 8000000000. },
 { "TiBps", 8.*1024.*1024.*1024.*1024. },
 { "TBps", 8000000000000. },
 { NULL }
}

Comment: According to [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux_net/fLTsPEM255o%5B101-125%5D) (2009), htb isn't supposed to handle more than 1Gb/s "or maybe a little more". According to your experience, it looks like 160 Mibps (1.28 Gb/s) is the maximum htb can be accurate with.